# Double substitution in an indefinite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I am training my self in solving  integrals by substitution and I have a doubt in applying a double substitution.

To solve the integral $\int \sin^4{(7x)}\cos{(7x)}\, dx$ I have thought to do the substitution $t\to u$, so: $u=7x$ and then $du=7dx$, and hence:
$$\int \sin^4{(7x)}\cos{(7x)}\, dx=\frac{1}{7}\int \sin^4{(u)}\cos{(u)}\, du$$
Now if I want to write $w=\sin{u}\implies dw=\cos{u}\,du$, so the integral becomes:
$$\frac{1}{7}\int w^4 \, dw$$
$\textbf{Question:}$ is it right to write $dw=\cos{u}\,du$ and so considering that the derivative of $w$ with respect $u$ is $\cos{u}$ or I have to apply the chain rule of derivation and taking into the account that $u$ is a function of $x$ ($dw=7\cos{7x}\,dx$)?

Comment: When you change from $u$ to $w$ there is no need to remember that $u=7x$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok thanks and this is due by the fact that I have to write who is $du$ in function of $dw$ right?

Comment: Yes, but at the end don't forget the constants of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is right.

---

Consider this: if you were given to solve $\int\sin^4u\cos u\,\text du$, then you would have done the same thing. It doesn't matter because now you are integrating something in $u$, not in $x$.

And even if you use chain rule, you will be getting $\text dx$, which you have to again change in order to make use of the $w$-substitution.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Ok thanks so if I applied the chain rule writing $dw=7\cos{7x}dx$ this would be useless since I need to write who is $\frac{dw}{du}$, right?

Comment: Exactly! Chain Rule doesn't fail, you can use it. But that would make the $w$-substitution useless, as you return back to the $x$-world!

Comment: Sorry if I ask many questions but I want to be sure to have understood... the substitution that would be useless is $u=7x$, right? since if I write $dw=7\cos{7x}\, dx$ then in rewriting $\frac{1}{7}\int sin^4{u}\cos{u}\, du$ I have to rewrite at first $du=7dx$ and then instead of $dx$ I write $\frac{dw}{7\cos{x}}$...so I am passing from $x$ to $u$ and from $w$ to $x$...so I am turning back to the variable from which I have started and so it has no sense the substituion, even if the solution would be still right?

Comment: @Sisi: Yes. The problem will be just where it started. And it's okay. You should know everything clearly, and we're here just to solve your queries!

Comment: Thanks a lot for having clairified all my doubts!

Comment: "And it's okay" means it's okay what I am stated in my comment or you are referring to the fact that even if I am turning back to the $x$ I will arrive at the result, even if it makes no sense the substitution of $u$?

Comment: @Sisi: I mean asking questions is okay. Getting an in-depth knowledge of the topic is necessary!

Comment: Ok so thanks both for confirming my ideas and my approach of studying!

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in doing more than one substitution. And there is no need to apply the chain rule here. At the end, you got $\frac1{28}w^5$. Since $w=\sin u$, this is the same thing as $\frac1{28}\sin^5u$. And, since $u=7x$, this is the same thing as $\frac1{28}\sin^5(7x)$.

Of course, after noticing that the substitutions $u=7x$ and $w=\sin u$ solve your problem, you could use the single substitution $w=\sin(7x)$ and then, yes, you should use the chain rule to know that then $\mathrm dw=7\cos(7x)\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Ok thanks! The single substitution suggested by you is better! But my idea helps me also to understand that in double substitution I have not to consider that $u$ is a function of $x$!

Answer (score 1):

You would see the answer to your question if instead you employed a single substitution of the form $$v = \sin 7x, \quad dv = 7 \cos 7x \, dx,$$ thus $$\int \sin^4 7x \cos 7x \, dx = \frac{1}{7} \int (\sin 7x)^4 (7 \cos 7x) \, dx = \frac{1}{7}\int v^4 \, dv.$$

In doing so, we employed the chain rule.  Since $u(x) = 7x$ and $w(u) = \sin u$, we have $v(x) = w(u(x))$, and $$\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dw}{du}\cdot \frac{du}{dx} = (\cos u(x))(7) = 7 \cos 7x.$$

Comment: Ok but here I apply the chain rule since I am rewriting $v$ as composition of $7x$ and sine...instead if I write $w=\sin{u}$ no chain rule, right?